# Datet and time picker pair validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datetimepicker

I want to0 set start and end date validation in datetimepicker .

this is my code but its not working.My requirement is if start date and time is selected then end date should not be less than start date and vice-versa.

Please help me with this if anyone know.

```
//for the start date of the calendar

$("#txt_event_start_date").datetimepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        $("#txt_event_end_date").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
});

//for the end date of the calendar

$("#txt_event_end_date").datetimepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        $("#txt_event_start_date").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you provide a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: ya...here it is...http://jsfiddle.net/cpxavier/faaohfLw/

Comment: would you add datepicker class aswell in fiddle, cause I am not able to see it

Comment: let me done with that and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling datetimepicker function on select event, you can call some validation function, which compares start date and end date. For example

```
 $("#txt_event_end_date").datetimepicker({
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     minDate: 0,
     onSelect: function () {
       validateForm();
   }
}); 
 validateForm() {
     var startDate = $("#txt_event_start_date").val();
     var endDate = $("#txt_event_start_date").val();

     if((new Date(startDate )).getTime() > (new Date(endDate )).getTime()) {
         alert("End date is before start date.")
     }
 }
```

Comment: i have solution for set min and max date in calender.But it didnt working with datetimepicker. And My Requirement is if user select start date and start time then end date should not be less then start date and end time should not be less then  start time...